# Changing blog style

Tags: css

I have done several websites for my employers business, all of which we are happy with. One thing i would like to change, however, is the style of the blog posts on one of the websites.

I would like to take the style we have on this website:
http://tradefreight.co.uk/shipping-nespresso-cube-to-galerie-lafayette-paris/

And use it on this one:
http://irishgroupage.co.uk/size-doesnt-matter/

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks for any help provided.

Andy

Answer (score 2):

The styling of WordPress sites is nearly exclusively defined by its theme.

You can typically discover theme by examining the source for `style.css` file, which contains header with theme information.

In this specific case it would be commercial [Porto](http://spyropress.com/themes/porto) theme, which you can purchase and use for your site.